# How to get image src from specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My sample **html** section with **several items** like this:

```
<ul class="catalog">
  <li class="catalog_item catalog_item--default-view">
    <div class="catalog_item_image">
      <img src="/img/01.png" alt="model01" class="catalog_item_icons__big-foto">
   </div>
   <ul class="catalog_item_icons">
      <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview"><img src="/img/01-01.png" alt="01" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small"></li>
      <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview"><img src="/img/01-02.png" alt="02" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small"></li>
      <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview"><img src="/img/01-03.png" alt="03" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small"></li>
   </ul>
```

I want to 
change src of **img.catalog_item_icons__big-foto** 
  with 
src of **img.catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small**

after clicking on li element **only in it's parent** ul.catalog.

That was my try:

```
$(".catalog_item_icons__preview").each(function () {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    console.log('Clicked preview!');
    // get image fileName
    var smallImagePath = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
    console.log("small image: " + smallImagePath);
    var $bigPreview = $(this).closest('img.catalog_item_icons__big-foto').attr("src");

    // print in console src of nearest big image
    console.log($bigPreview);

  });

});
```

I can get the src of small image, but can't even read the src of the img above in tree.
Output in console: undefined. Don't understand why :(

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: `$('.catalog_item_image img').attr('src')`?

Comment: closest looks at parents, the element is not a parent as it travels up the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //It is executing a function when it is clicked on an item
    $('.catalog_item_icons li').click(function() {
        //Taking the source of the image of the clicked element.
        //with $('img', this) you are choosing the the image in the clicked element
        _src = $('img', this).attr('src');
        //In the next line I am assigning to the _obj variable - the parent .catalog_item--default-view of the clicked element
        _obj = $(this).parents('.catalog_item--default-view');
        //In the next line i am changing the source attribute of the .catalog_item_icons__big-foto located in the _obj object
        $('.catalog_item_icons__big-foto', _obj).attr('src', _src);
    });
});
```

Comment: Viktor, many thanks!
That's worked! But I'm still don't understand what it dircetly does:
_src - src attribute of the image i've been clicked
_obj - ? this is for selecting needed element 

$('.catalog_item_icons__big-foto', _obj).attr('src', _src);
many thanks for this? am i right, with this we changing src of selected object?

Comment: Please if I have helped you approve my answer and vote for it. I will change the post with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: My reputation doesn't enough for voting. this is my first question here

Comment: I changed my post with comments of how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

catalog_item_icons__big-foto is not a direct ancestor so closest will not find it. The closest metod looks at itself and than looks at parents. The element you are looking for is not a parent, it is a child of one of those parents.

Easiest thing is to look for the top li and find the image from there.

```
$(this).closest(".catalog_item catalog_item--default-view")
    .find('img.catalog_item_icons__big-foto')
```

or option is to find the parent ul and find the previous sibling and than find the image.

Answer (score 0):

problem is here The closest() method returns the first ancestor of the selected element.An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on.

```
 var $bigPreview = $(this).closest('img.catalog_item_icons__big-foto').attr("src");
```

you just use class that will work for you

```
 var $bigPreview = $('img.catalog_item_icons__big-foto').attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, check console following code is working for me

```
$("li.catalog_item_icons__preview").on("click", function(){
    // get image fileName
    var smallImagePath = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
    console.log("small image: " + smallImagePath);
    var bigPreview = $(this).parent('ul').siblings(".catalog_item_image").children(".catalog_item_icons__big-foto").attr("src");

    // print in console src of nearest big image
    console.log(bigPreview);
});
```

```js
$("li.catalog_item_icons__preview").on("click", function(){
    // get image fileName
    var smallImagePath = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
    console.log("small image: " + smallImagePath);
    var bigPreview = $(this).parent('ul').siblings(".catalog_item_image").children(".catalog_item_icons__big-foto").attr("src");

    // print in console src of nearest big image
    console.log(bigPreview);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="catalog">
  <li class="catalog_item catalog_item--default-view">
    <div class="catalog_item_image">
      <img src="/img/01.png" alt="model01" class="catalog_item_icons__big-foto">
   </div>
   <ul class="catalog_item_icons">
      <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview"><img src="/img/01-01.png" alt="01" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small"></li>
      <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview"><img src="/img/01-02.png" alt="02" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small"></li>
      <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview"><img src="/img/01-03.png" alt="03" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small"></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(".catalog_item_icons__preview").click(function() {
  $(".catalog_item_icons__big-foto").attr("src", $(this).children("img").attr("src"));
  console.log($(".catalog_item_icons__big-foto").attr("src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog_item_image">
  <img src="/img/01.png" alt="model01" class="catalog_item_icons__big-foto">
</div>
<ul class="catalog_item_icons">
  <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview">
    <img src="/img/01-01.png" alt="01" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small">
  </li>
  <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview">
    <img src="/img/01-02.png" alt="02" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small">
  </li>
  <li class="catalog_item_icons__preview">
    <img src="/img/01-03.png" alt="03" class="catalog_item_icons__preview--foto-small">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this change **image of all elemnts**, but for my task scope is in current div, where li with small image is.

Comment: Chage `$(".catalog_item_icons__big-foto").attr("src", $(this).children("img").attr("src"));`  to   `$(this).parrents(".catalog_item_icons__big-foto").attr("src", $(this).children("img").attr("src"));`

Comment: Thanks Krupesh! I will try your solution, but best solution was the first [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33478662/3105096) provided by@Viktor Maksimov